# Read FileMaker data without opening files/databases first?

Tags: database, odbc, export, loading, filemaker

I managed to read data from FileMaker databases via Microsoft Access' ODBC import wizard. The problem is that every file needs to be opened first in FileMaker itself before it is made available via ODBC/JDBC.

This is an issue, because the data will change and I need to export the data of 150 databases every other week. I don't want to the enter the different credentials for every single database every other week, and wait for FileMaker to tell me, that some linked databases are not found (takes approx. 10 hours of supervision, only to hit the Cancel button).

Is there any way to avoid this tedious loading procedure? Does FileMaker Server work differently in this regard? (all databases always available?)

Comment: I don't think we have enough information here to provide an intelligent answer. If those 150 files are constant. you could automate the process by creating a new file containing references to those files (and/or their tables). Not sure how that would behave with missing references, though.  Perhaps you ought to put your house in order first. And consolidate at least some of those files to a more manageable number.

Comment: Basically every file has a completely different structure, they can't be merged content-wise. Is there still a way to "reference" all files in a way, so that I would only open one file that implicitly loads all others? (I guess I could write a small program to automatically click on Cancel whenever needed if there's no other way to access the data)

Comment: I meant consolidate the **files**, not (necessarily) their tables. Ever since version 7, a file can contain multiple tables. -- And yes, you can use a single file to open multiple files, either explicitly: http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/scripts_ref1.35.110.html#1109628 or implicitly: http://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/relational.12.14.html#1028611

Comment: The files were created with a very early FileMaker version and later upgraded to v7. It should be one table per file. I'll test to setup relationships as explained in your 2nd link. If I wanted to use a script (1st link), would I need a blank database to run it it? I did XML exports last years, but I had to add my export script to every file first - wasn't convenient at all. Is there a way to run a script on arbitrary databases without modifying them?

Comment: If you place an external table on the graph and create a layout for it, you can then export from that table (including scripted export), without having to modify the original file containing the actual table.

Comment: I added two tables from two files to a new database, and I can see the 3 table names in Access via ODBC, but there's an error for both external files (can't find object X) if I try to import them. One of the external files was opened in FileMaker, the other wasn't. Do I need to create a layout with layout fields for every field/column in the external tables to be able to access the data? (some sort of indirection)

Comment: In order to export, you must have a layout for each table. The layout itself can be blank. I am not sure what the situation is when attempting ODBC from outside. I am quite sure there is no way to get data out of a file unless that file is open in Filemaker. Filemaker will open referenced files as needed (sometimes they'll be open, but hidden).

Answer (score 2):

FileMaker Server would be able to host the databases so they are available via ODBC, assuming ODBC has been enabled on the server and that the files you are accessing have been set up to allow ODBC sharing in their security settings.

It could also be an option to export the data you need out of FileMaker to a more friendly format that Access can consume. Could that be a possibility?

Comment: The data will be migrated to another system, but since it's a live system, there are still changed made (including clean-up work as preparation for the pending migration). The changes partially rely on analyses of the very same data. There will be several iterations of the export and import, and I would like these to be fast and short cycles. Access was an ODBC connectivity test. If FileMaker Server can host all files, that's great (although we can't have them all simultaneously on the same machine due to technical limitations). Would I specify user and password in the ODBC connection string?

Comment: I know you can in jdbc, for odbc specifying the password may be part of the DSN setup. You could optionally set the FM files to open by default with an ODBC enabled account.

Comment: It would baffle me if it only asked for one user and password, because every database has different credentials. I can specify a single credential in the ODBC setup, for one database. If I needed to create one ODBC connection per database, that would be as bad as opening all files individually in FileMaker Pro...

Answer (score 0):

If you have 150 Filemaker databases to open you can do this:

1. Create a Filemaker file
2. Create two accounts (example: Admin and Admin2)
3. Create a Script that verifies if Admin or Admin2 is the current user
4. If the current user is Admin Program your script to work, else,exit the script
5. The script basically opens the files and does somthing with them
6. Adjust the Filemaker file to start automaticaly (file options) with the Admin and iths password.
7. Adjust the Script to run at startup

NOTE: if you need to make changes, open the file with Shift pressed so it will ask for a user and pass. Use Admin2 and the script will exit.
WARNING: Very important to have this working. Will be very difficult to debug if such a mechanism is not stablished.

Now, once tested (Admin and Admin2), you can open your files and do someting with them and exit filemaker once done. I usually make two scripts. The first one runs at startup and verifies the user: if is Admin runs the second script, if it is Admin2 exits the script.

The second script contains what ever you need to do.